# Get intrinsic content size of a label to render new image

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, label

I'm working on an app which creates a physical postcard from the user's screen.  In order render the final postcard image I redraw the views shown to the user and use  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() to get a final image for printing.  This works fine.

The problem is that my date label is centered in the screen and I'm using auto layout and intrinsic content size to set the placement of the date label.  This is so it will always be centered no matter how many characters in the month name (June vs. September give different placements).  When I redraw this I cannot set a rectangle for my dateLabel in my ImageContext because I don't know exactly where the label is.  Right before I redraw the screen in an ImageContext I need to know exactly where my date label is.  I tried accessing intrinsic content size this way:
`CGSize *labelSize = self.dateLabel.intrinsicContentSize;`

This gives the error : initializing 'CGSize *'(aka struct CGSize *') with an expression of incompatible type 'CGSize'(aka 'struct CGSize')

How can I get the exact placement (x,y,width,height) of the label that is set to intrinsic content size in order to redraw the label in my ImageContext?

Comment: `CGSize labelSize = self.dateLabel.intrinsicContentSize;`? (Without the "*")

Comment: That was the problem, thanks!